# Mongoose difficulty understanding how to correctly use promises/async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a nodejs back end with express handling the routing for my API to my mongo DB using Mongoose. I have changed the code so its easier to understand but essentially I am building a task list.

I have an endpoint for adding tasks to a tasklist, I want to maintain a list of tasks to perform some analysis on later. The problem that I am having is that I want to check whether a task exists already, if that task doesnt exist then I want to create it in my task model and then add it to my taskList. If it does exist then I just want to add it to my task list.

My first thought was to use async on the save operation when creating a task because I wanted to avoid nesting loads of promises because that makes it quite unreadable. But when my nodejs server starts it gives me an error `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` but from the documentation you can use await on save, and my function has the async keyword. so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
exports.tasklists_add_task = async (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.tasklistId;

    Task.findOne({ externalId: req.body.externalId })
        .exec()
        .then(doc => {

            let task = doc;

            if (!task) {
                task = new Task({
                    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                    externalId: req.body.externalId,
                    name: req.body.name
                });

                await task.save();
            }
            tasklist.update({_id: id}, {$push: { tasks: tasks }})
            .select("-__v")
            .exec() 
        })
        .then(result => {
            ...
        })
        .catch(err => { ... })
}
```

I have 2 schemas a Task Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    externalId: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Task", taskSchema);
```

and a Task List Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const taskListSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    type: { type: String, required: true },
    tasks: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Type" }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("TaskList", taskListSchema);
```

I don't have to use async await here, I could just chain promises, but I couldn't work out how to chain the promises in a logical readable way since I have to create the task if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await` is allowed only in async functions (providing you're using environment that supports it). `Await` works only in `async` function and your `await` is inside callback that's not async - only your top function is `async`. You missed the keyword here:

```
.then(doc => {

// Should be:
.then(async doc => {
```

This way you're telling your code that `doc` callback is async function. However, as you're having `async/await` in your environment, this whole block may be refactored to look like that!

```
exports.tasklists_add_task = async (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.tasklistId;

  try {
    let task = await Task.findOne({ externalId: req.body.externalId })
      .exec();

    if (!task) {
       task = new Task({
         _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
         externalId: req.body.externalId,
         name: req.body.name
       });

       await task.save();
    }

    const result = await tasklist.update({_id: id}, {$push: { tasks: tasks }}).select("-__v").exec();
  } catch (err) {
    // Error handling here
  } 
}
```

There's no need to mix `async/await` and `then`s in most of the cases. Think of it as of fancy way of handling promises and hiding `then/catch` behind sequential, readable code.

I'd recommend to adjust the code so it looks as presented solution (mixing Promises and Async/Await heavily is considered somewhat of anti-pattern).

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was wanting, thank you, it makes a lot of sense now that my async should have been on the then of my findOne. I haven't really looked into async await properly yet so I really appreciate the refactor.